# Word to describe people engaged in "credit card fraud"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I find the word "fraudster" a little bit silly-sounding when used in a serious context.  Do there exist any synonyms that are more usable in professional discussions of fraud?

I'm mostly interested in describing people who are engaged in **credit card fraud**.

Comment: The word is used currently in the serious context of Canadian parliament debates (unless you count anything Canadian "funny" as some people from the south thinks so). http://www.parl.gc.ca/HousePublications/Publication.aspx?DocId=4819346&Language=E&Mode=1  . Although it is not used in the text of laws.

Comment: I believe [charlatan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charlatan) would well describe what you're talking about, but you'll probably sound just as silly

Comment: "credit card crook" ?

Comment: I wonder if this question might offer an opening for eponymous coinage: a "madoff"?  Wikipedia describes Bernie Madoff as a "fraudster."

Comment: I tend to defer to the BBC in matters of language correctness: in this article about a convicted credit card "fraudster", they only ever refer to him as "the defendant" or by his actual name.  http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-33442419

Comment: White collar criminals!

Answer (score 3):

You can just say "fraud", which applies to the person committing the crime as well as the crime itself.  eg "He is a fraud".

Comment: I think this works in some cases, but it sounds a bit strange in others (e.g., "...a strategy used by frauds..."), probably because this usage seems to have a slightly informal connotation that doesn't always translate to situations where we're talking (for instance) about people who commit fraud for a living.  I'm mostly interested in talking about professional "fraudsters," which may not have been clear in the original post.

Comment: I think in a legal discussion you would say something like "the person convicted of fraudulent activity".

Comment: @dsaxton Adding a sample sentence (as the single-word-requests tag requires) would help the community find a better word for the context *you* have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Swindler, confidence man, defaulter, embezzler... any of those work for you? There are also some specialized terms for certain types of fraud (e.g. shark for pool or card playing). It depends a bit what you're looking for.

Comment: We'd be describing people who commit credit card fraud (I edited my original post).

Comment: How about "defrauder"? It is an accurate if somewhat clumsy term.

Comment: I think that actually sounds better than fraudster.  Good suggestion.

Comment: 'con-man' is much more common than the spelled out version and is someone who does this habitually. 'defrauder' is a legal construction but just not used. 'Embezzler' is used but refers to a very specific type of fraud. 'Swindler' sounds best to me but might be a little old fashioned. For the OP, there's no need to have a single noun for this, just say 'that person stole my credit card #'

Comment: And don't forget "scam artist", or simply "scammer".

Answer (score 1):

***Scammer*** might work. *[Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scammer)* categorizes it as slang:

> a person who perpetrates a scam; swindler

But [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scammer&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows its frequency in books increasing almost 28-fold between 1985 and 2008, so maybe that categorization needs revisiting.

Answer (score 1):

I think **grifter** has a suitably sinister tone. *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this entry for the verb *grift*:

> **grift** *vb* {*grift*, n., perh. alter. of *graft*} *vt* (1915) **:** to obtain (money) illicitly (as in a confidence game) **~** *vi* **:** to to acquire money or property illicitly — **grift** *n* — **grifter** *n*

So a *grifter* is a person who acquires money or property illicitly, as through a confidence game, a scam, or some other form of fraud.

Comment: I like this one, even though I think it's just a bit dated - an idiosyncratic sense of connotation that I can't verify. (Perhaps I, too, am a bit dated.)